# Cocoa: create drop zone for files

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop

I want to create a drag and drop zone (using an NSView) for ANY file in my cocoa app.  How do I do it?

Comment: Okay, seriously, what the ----? Do you think you could maybe flesh that out a little? What do you mean by "zone"? Do you mean part of the UI, memory etc. Are you asking how to detect file types? If you want people to spend more than 20 seconds on your question you might spend more than 20 seconds writing it.

Comment: as in an NSView area, where I can drop files into it from anywhere in my computer, and get the path of that file to do whatever I want.  Not to sound like a jerk, but it's kinda implied in the question with "drag and drop"

Comment: matt: “Drag and drop” can also mean on your application icon in Finder, on your running Dock tile, or on your non-running Dock tile. TechZen's comment was harsher than I would have written it, but it was correct: You needed to be more specific.

Comment: I fixed it to be at least a little more specific

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read [Drag and Drop Programming Topics for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html). You want your custom view to be a "dragging destination". You'll need to understand the pasteboard and file path pasteboard types, how to subclass a view (a generic NSView for your own custom class, or an existing view like NSImageView) and add the appropriate dragging source methods.